# incorrect value of timestampdiff being passed in java result set variable

Tags: java, mysql

I have a simple requirement of getting timestampdifF in mysql database and use the resultset value in java code to check a condition if the timestampdiff is greater than 15 minutes, if yes do some update in DB or else skip and continue the next flow.

However, I am not getting the correct value when I pass the result set value in Java. The same query returns the correct value when executed on the database directly. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String Diff = null;
try {
    conn = Daofactory.getconnection();
    String sql = "select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,max(start_tstamp),NOW()) as timediff from app.process_log where status = 'P'";
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        log.info("Inside while loop");
        Diff = rs.getString(1);
    }
    if(Diff.equalsIgnoreCase("15")) {
        String sql1 = "update statement here";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
        int i = stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
```

When I execute the query on DB directly it returns the correct value in minutes; however, when I run the program the timeDiff is always 0. How can I fix this?

Comment: Right after Diff = rs.getString(1); can you add System.out.printline("the diff is " + Diff); and tell us what it prints?

Comment: I added the logger and SOP both print the same thing "0". Not sure why its not getting the value that i get when i execute the query in DB directly.

Comment: @user3813777 did you solve your problem? If so please share the solution since I am facing the same problem as you did.